# mod-rewrite subdomain to path in primary domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns, subdomain

I have content from a different server on a subdomain that I would like to use as a subdirectory. Everything from sub.domain.com should be accessible to domain.com/sub  I would like sub folders to work as well ex: sub.domain.com/about should be domain.com/sub/about

Here's my current .htaccess contents

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^(sorry).* - [NC,L]
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/sub%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks, but having a conflict. Here's my current .htaccess contents: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^(sorry).* - [NC,L]
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: You need to put above code on top of your other .htaccess stuff.

Comment: Thanks again.  But I'm getting a page not found.  The index.php file is in a folder called /app and there is an .htaccess file with <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule> there and also in /app/webroot

Comment: What is the URI that you get in your browser?

Comment: Yes that's what you wanted isn't it. If you enter `sub.domain.com/about` my answer will make it `domain.com/sub/about` as well

Comment: Oh sorry, i get domain.com/sub in my browser and it throws a page not found.  This is tricky... the client is ok with just using a subdomain but i'm still curious how to do this virtual subdirectory stuff though!

Comment: Are you getting `http://sub.domain.com/about` redirected to `http://domain.com/sub` as per my rules you should get `http://domain.com/sub/about`